# Unable to strip the following libraries, packaging them as they are: librealm.so

Tags: react-native, realm

I got this:

> Unable to strip the following libraries, packaging them as they are: librealm.so.

After running `yarn add realm` into my React-Native app. I did it using react-native cli, not expo. The thing is after running `npx react-native run-android` I got that warning (?) but the app compiles successfully but it closes the Application from my virtual device.

Using react 17.0.2, react-native 0.68.1 and realm 10.16.0.

I uninstalled realm and everything worked as expected. Installed realm again and I got this. I have been googleing and I found nothing related to this. Any help?

Comment: The complete setup for Realm on Android CLI is here [React Native CLI Quickstart](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup). Look through those steps and see if anything was missed. I would then try using the template (as shown in the guide) and see if it also throws an error.

Comment: Thanks @Jay, but no missing steps.